# How to check if facebook LoginButton is clicked?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I want to know if the facebook `LoginButton` is clicked, so that i can put handle if there is an internet connection problem or not. I can't seem find how to do it, is there any solution to this? I'm wondering if `loginButton.callOnClick` can handle this? Thank you for the help.

I'm using Facebook SDK

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1'`

Comment: Facebook doesnt provide the access to `LoginClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they didn't allow . they check it by themselves

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
          // Log.d("Login", "onSuccess");
           GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                   loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                       @Override
                       public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {

                       }
                   }).executeAsync();
       }


       @Override
       public void onCancel () {
         //  Log.d("Login", "onCancel");
       }

       @Override
       public void onError (FacebookException e){
         //  Log.d("Login", "onError " + e);
           if(!NetworkStatus.getInstance(context).isConnectedToInternet()){
              //show network error
           }
       }
   };
```

Comment: but I can check in `onError()` ?

Comment: yes you can check there . That is what i mentioned there by comment

Comment: how about the connection timeout can i also check inside `onError` ?

Comment: for list of error exception list check the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/exception/FacebookException/